# Generate Menu Tree from XML / JSON Category with Slash Delimiter

Tags: php, mysql, xml, json

I am trying to create an HTML menu on the fly from a result returned from the Adobe Scene7 Metadata Server.  The categories will be based on their folder path property. An example of the data is here:

```
<asset assetName="company_logo" assetId="1832">
    <fields>
        <field name="s7core.folderpath" value="top/this_project/Logos/"/>
        <field name="s7core.name" value="company_logo"/>
    </fields>
</asset>
<asset assetName="Product_Name_Would_Be_Here" assetId="1896">
    <fields>
        <field name="s7core.folderpath" value="top/this_project/Product Images/Child1/Child2/"/>
        <field name="s7core.name" value="Product_Name_Would_Be_Here"/>
    </fields>
</asset>
```

I can also get the results in JSON like this:

```
{
    "status": {
        "code":0,
        "severity":"OK",
        "message":"ok"
    },
    "assets": [
        {
            "assetId":1832,
            "assetName":"company_logo",
            "fields": {
                "s7core.folderpath":"top/this_project/Logos/",
                "s7core.name":"company_logo"
            }
        },
        {
            "assetId":1896,
            "assetName":"Product_Name_Here",
            "fields":{
                "s7core.folderpath":"top/this_project/Product Images/Child1/Child2/",
                "s7core.name":"Product_Name_Here"
            }
        }
```

In this example, Product Images and Logos would be parent categories, with different children under them. I am just looking to be able to take these results and generate either a menu on the fly, or update a MySQL table with parent/child relationships so I can query and process this.

My final result would be something similar to:

```
<UL class="parent">
     <LI>Top</LI>
          <UL class="child-1">
               <LI>This Project</LI>
          <UL class="child-2">
               <LI>Logos</LI>
               <LI>Product Images</LI>
          <UL class="child-3">
               <LI>Child 1</LI>
                    <UL class="child-4">
                         <LI>Child 2</LI>
                    </UL>
          </UL>
          </UL>
          </UL>
</UL>
```

I can import the values all into MySQL and query out the structure from there, I'm just looking for something to parse out the folder paths, delimit by the / marks, and create that hierarchy of lists.  The menu will then link into a gallery viewer which will query the server based on the category chosen to find the full results of products that match.

I considered using Magmi to process these categories, as they are in the same format as importing into a Magento installation, but that just seems like overkill to process these categories into a fly-out menu.

Thanks again.

Comment: Nice background info, but expected results and showing what you've tried already might help here.

Comment: From your information, it is not clear from me how to derive menu hierarchy from the data provided. I also don't see how you derive li text such as `This Project`, `Logos`, `Product Images`, etc. from the data provided.  These strings are not present at all in the data source.

Comment: The folderpath value will be a string like "Parent/Sub Cat 1/Sub Cat 2". So for instance, in a t-shirt shop, some results could be "Shirts/Color/Blue", "Shirts/Color/Red", "Shirts/Size/Small", Shirts/Size/XXL", "Shirts/Designer/Bob Johnson", "Shirts/Designer/Judy Walsh".  Now, the menu would have an overall parent of "Shirts", with sub categories of Color, Size, and Designer, with the respective sub categories below them.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking to do, only with PHP and not using Magmi - as that is a product importer for Magento.  But this article explains exactly what I'm working with. http://www.blinkdata.com/magmi-on-the-fly-category-creator/